# Why is Tanstack Table giving me a type mismatch in my cell definition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstack

I've been learning how to use react and typescript recently and am currently trying to use Tanstack Table to define a complicated table using generic types for reusability. I'm running into type errors with how I am trying to spread my custom function for cell definition.

The error:

> Argument of type '{ getUniqueValues?: AccessorFn<BulkEditRow, unknown[]> | undefined; footer?: ColumnDefTemplate<HeaderContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>> | undefined; ... 22 more ...; id: string; } | ... 6 more ... | { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IdentifiedColumnDef<BulkEditRow, number | null>'.
> Type '{ getUniqueValues?: AccessorFn<BulkEditRow, unknown[]> | undefined; footer?: ColumnDefTemplate<HeaderContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>> | undefined; ... 22 more ...; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IdentifiedColumnDef<BulkEditRow, number | null>'.
> Types of property 'cell' are incompatible.
> Type 'ColumnDefTemplate<CellContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDefTemplate<CellContext<BulkEditRow, number | null>> | undefined'.
> Type '(props: CellContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>) => any' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDefTemplate<CellContext<BulkEditRow, number | null>> | undefined'.
> Type '(props: CellContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>) => any' is not assignable to type '(props: CellContext<BulkEditRow, number | null>) => any'.
> Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
> Type 'CellContext<BulkEditRow, number | null>' is not assignable to type 'CellContext<BulkEditRow, unknown>'.
> The types of 'cell.column.columnDef' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'ColumnDef<BulkEditRow, number | null>' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDef<BulkEditRow, unknown>'.
> Type 'ColumnDefBase<BulkEditRow, number | null> & StringHeaderIdentifier' is not assignable to type 'ColumnDef<BulkEditRow, unknown>'.
> Type 'ColumnDefBase<BulkEditRow, number | null> & StringHeaderIdentifier' is not assignable to type 'AccessorFnColumnDefBase<BulkEditRow, unknown> & IdIdentifier<BulkEditRow, unknown>'.
> Property 'accessorFn' is missing in type 'ColumnDefBase<BulkEditRow, number | null> & StringHeaderIdentifier' but required in type 'AccessorFnColumnDefBase<BulkEditRow, unknown>'.ts(2345)
> types.d.ts(83, 5): 'accessorFn' is declared here.
> (property) IdentifiedColumnDef<BulkEditRow, number | null>.header?: ColumnDefTemplate<HeaderContext<BulkEditRow, number | null>> | undefined

I pass to a function that determines what should be returned

```
export const useEditableCell = <TData extends object>(
  setTableState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TableState>>,
  getTableState: TableState,
  customUpdateFunction?: CustomUpdateFunction,
  mode: 'View' | 'Edit' = 'Edit'
) => {
  const editableColumn = useMemo<Partial<ColumnDef<TData>>>(() => {
    return {
      cell: (cellProps) => {
        const isCurrentErrorCell =
          getTableState.errorLocation &&
          cellProps.row.index === getTableState.errorLocation.rowIndex &&
          cellProps.column.id === getTableState.errorLocation.columnId

        const cellValue = cellProps.getValue()
        const displayValue = cellValue === null ? '' : String(cellValue)

        if (
          (getTableState.message != null && !isCurrentErrorCell) ||
          mode === 'View'
        ) {
          return <TableDisplayCell value={displayValue} />
        }

        return (
          <EditableCell
            {...(cellProps as unknown as Cell<TData, unknown>)}
            updateData={
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
              customUpdateFunction ?? cellProps.table.options.meta!.updateData
            }
            setTableState={setTableState}
          />
        )
      },
    }
  }, [
    getTableState.errorLocation,
    getTableState.message,
    mode,
    customUpdateFunction,
    setTableState,
  ])

  return editableColumn
}
```

This then returns either a cell that is editable using mui textfield or div with a display value inside.

Here is how the useEditableCell is used:

```
const editableCell = useEditableCell<BulkEditRow>(
    setTableState,
    getTableState
  )
```

And then used inside the column definitions here:

```
 columnHelper.accessor('percentAustralia', {
        id: 'percentAustralia',
        header: () => RenderDefaultHeaderCell('% Australia'),
        size: 12,
        meta: {
          validate: validatePercentageValueInTable,
        },
        ...editableCell,
      }),
```

I'm just very confused on why this doesn't work when if I were to simply define the column like so:

```
 cell: (cellProps) => {
    <EditableCell
            {...(cellProps as unknown as Cell<TData, unknown>)}
            updateData={
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
              cellProps.table.options.meta!.updateData
            }
            setTableState={setTableState}
     />
  }
```

It works fine. Any help would be appreciated, though everything I am doing is done with a purpose and a specific use case in mind, so I cannot change anything that I am doing.